# 3D движок Ursina. Не работает часть кода с mouse.hovered

Tags: python, 3d, ursina

Недавно я начал изучать движок ursina позволяющий работать с 3D в Python. Следовал официальному туториалу для чайников - не работает часть кода с `mouse.hovered`. В чём проблема / что я сделал неправильно?

```py
from ursina import *
import random

#Запуск игры
app = Ursina()
window.title = 'Ursina tutorial'
window.borderless = False
window.fullscreen = False
window.exit_button.visible = False
window.fps_counter.enabled = True  

def rnd(min, max):
    return random.randint(min, max)

#Обновление
def update():
    delta = time.dt
    if held_keys['a']:
        for cube in cubes:
            cube.rotation_y += delta * 50
    if held_keys['d']:
        for cube in cubes:
            cube.rotation_y -= delta * 50
    if held_keys['w']:
        for cube in cubes:
            cube.rotation_x += delta * 50
    if held_keys['s']:
        for cube in cubes:
            cube.rotation_x -= delta * 50

    if held_keys['up arrow']:
        camera.position += (0, 0, 100 * delta)
    elif held_keys['down arrow']:
        camera.position -= (0, 0, 100 * delta)


    if mouse.hovered_entity == cubes[0]: #Часть проблемного кода
        info.visible = True
    else:
        info.visible = False

    global offset

    offset += delta * 0.5
    setattr(cubes[0], "texture_offset", (0, offset)) #То к чему линкуем, параметр линка, (х,у)

def input(key):
    if key == 'space':
        for cub in cubes:
            cub.color = color.rgb(rnd(0, 255), rnd(0, 255), rnd(0,255))
    elif key == 'c':
        cubes.append(Entity(parent = cube, model = 'cube', color = color.rgb(rnd(0, 255), rnd(0, 255), rnd(0,255)), scale = (rnd(1, 2), rnd(1, 2), rnd(1,2)), position = (rnd(-5, 5), rnd(-5, 5), rnd(-5,5))))
    elif key == 'r':
        cubes.append(Entity(model = 'cube', color = color.rgb(rnd(0, 255), rnd(0, 255), rnd(0,255)), scale = (rnd(1, 2), rnd(1, 2), rnd(1,2)), position = (rnd(-5, 5), rnd(-5, 5), rnd(-5,5))))
    elif key == 'escape':
        exit()

cubes = []
cube = Entity(model = 'cube', color = color.rgba(255, 255, 255, 128), scale = (2,6,1), texture = "water")
cubes.append(cube)

offset = 0.0

Text.size = 0.05
Text.default_resolution = 1080 * Text.size
info = Text(text = "lol")
info.x = 0.5
info.y = 0.4
info.background = True
info.visible = True


app.run()
```

Comment: Так выполнение кода вроде начинается с пустого у вас метода main?

Comment: @МаксимФисман можно и так и так - всё работает кроме mouse.hovering